# CMake: Avoid adding libraries more than once

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries

I am trying to set up a C++ project using CMake. In the end, there will be at least two big libraries, that I will need to use.

Those big libraries themselves, lets call them LIB1 and LIB2, depend on another library, called LIB3. I also want to directly use LIB3.

LIB1 and LIB2 are including LIB3 automaticly using their Find.cmake files.

My question is: Does CMake notice, that LIB1 and LIB2 are including the same library? Do I even need to specify in the main CMakeLists.txt, that I want to use LIB3, too, as a direct dependency of my main application?

How can I guarantee, that if there is more than one version of LIB3, that all other libs are including the same files?

Comment: If you set up the target dependencies correctly then only one of each library needed will be used by CMake. Not that it matters since even for static libraries it should not actually include the libraries twice. Once a symbol have been resolved and put into the executable, the linker will not search for that symbol in other libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Does that mean, that it is good style to include LIB3 explicitly in the root CMakeLists.txt, so that the dependency is not hidden behind another lib?

Comment: The FindLib3.cmake script probably already sets up `LIB3` as a top-level imported library-target, which means you only have to add it to to the dependency list of `LIB1` and `LIB2`, then CMake will automatically handle it for you. You might do it with the [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) command, like `add_dependencies(LIB1 LIB3)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude LIB1 and LIB2 are not libraries I wrote myself. More concretly, I am trying to set up the PointCloudLibrary (PCL). PCL has it's own Config, that does include f.a. Boost by itself.
Given this context, I could find Boost  at first, but after that I need to find PCL, which than does search for Boost, without me being able to avoid that (as far as I know). So what should I do?

Link to PCL: http://pointclouds.org/